# updating text on view from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, panel

I have problem with updating view by using ng-repeat.
When click on text, it doesnt update but it overwrites below. (I want have panel with names(links) and show its description on view)
I have searched everything and couldnt find answer or something useful what would help me.

html:

```
 <body>
    <div  ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <ul>
                <li><a   ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="getInfo(item)" > {{item.name}} <br> </a></li>
            </ul>                           
        </div>
        <hr>

            <div ng-controller="myInfo"> 
                <div   ng-repeat="info in item"  >  
                <h3>Name: {{info.name}}</h3>
                    <p> ID: {{info._id}}</p>
                    <p> temp: {{info.temp}}  </p>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div> 

  </body>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, shareDataService) {
      $http.jsonp('data.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.items = data;

        });
        $scope.getInfo = function(item) {
            shareDataService.addItem(item);

    }
});
app.controller('myInfo', function( $scope, shareDataService ){
    $scope.item = shareDataService.getItem();
});
app.service('shareDataService', function() {
  var myItem = [];

  var addItem = function(newObj) {
      myItem.push(newObj);
  }
  var getItem = function(){
      return myItem;
  }
  return {
    addItem: addItem,
    getItem: getItem
  };
});
```

json

```
angular.callbacks._0([
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "temp": "asdgdf",
        "name": "name1"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "temp": "asdasdasd",
        "name": "name2"
    },
     {
        "_id": 3,
        "temp": "asasdasdadgdf",
        "name": "name3"
    }
]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/X65oH0yAkRnN8npKnFY2?p=preview

Comment: can I clarify your requirements before posting an answer? are you trying to have the second `<div>` show a list of the items as you click them, or do you want it to exclusively show the last element clicked only?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your console. Just add `track by` to your ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="info in item track by $index">
```

ng-repeat needs a unique id to track the items in order to be able to update them. If you add the same item twice, ng-repeat sees the same item twice, ans loses its mind. Using $index (which is unique) resolves that issue.

Keep in mind that using $index is adequate here, but it's preferred to use a unique id from the object if you can.

EDIT:

If your issue is that you want to see only the one element you clicked on in your view, then the issue is that you are adding your item to an array, when you should just be setting a value in your service. And, obviously, no need of a `ng-repeat` in your view.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Wfg9KhCWKMDreTFtirhR?p=preview

JS:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, shareDataService) {
    //[...]
        $scope.getInfo = function(item) {
            shareDataService.setItem(item);
    }
});
app.controller('myInfo', function( $scope, shareDataService ){
  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return shareDataService.getItem();
  }, function (value) {
    $scope.info = value;
  })
});
app.service('shareDataService', function() {
  var myItem;

  return {
    setItem: function(newObj) {
      myItem = newObj;
    },
    getItem: function(){
      return myItem;
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
        <div ng-controller="myInfo" ng-show="info">  
            <h3>Name: {{info.name}}</h3>
                <p> ID: {{info._id}}</p>
                <p> temp: {{info.temp}}  </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display information of the item that you just have clicked, then we don't need the second *ng-repeat* (as jlowcs said). 
We also don't have to defined *myItem* as a array, it's just unnecessary, I think.

Edit: 
how embarrassing i am, my answer look exactly to same as jlowcs's. I guess I took to much time to figure out the answer.

One thing to add up:
Why do I need a $watch in myInfo controller?

Because at the first time, we use ng-repeat, this component do the watch part for us. Then when I remove ng-repeat, I need to watch for data changing by myself.